# Finding the min

Tags: function

I'm a beginner in python and having trouble with this function. I'm trying to count the values in list `xs` that are greater than `v` as well as the duplicates. I'm getting an error for line 3:

> NameError: name 'j' is not defined

Code below that I have:

```
def count_greater(xs,v):
    count_list = 0
    for i in (xs) and j in (v):
        if i > j:
            count_list += 1 
    else:
        count_list += 0
    return count_list 
count_greater([12,0,20,34,0,20],3)
```

How should I approach this? I am unsure on how to complete the rest of the logic.

Comment: `for i in (xs) and j in (v)` - what were you expecting that to do?

Comment: As `v` is just a single value then you probably meant `for i in xs: if i > v ...` And you really don't need the `else:` clause.

Comment: I fixed some spacing errors. I'm trying to count the values in the list xs that are greater than v.

Comment: Do you want to return the number of times that there is a value in the list that is greater, or the values that are greater?

Comment: `for i in (xs) and j in (v):` is is not valid syntax. Either `v` is not iterable, in which case simply `for i in xs:` is all you need, or `v` is another iterable, and you need to nest your for-loops or loop over pairs using zip.

Comment: Also, Alan, in the future, if you are getting an error, **post the error in your question**

Comment: Will screencap in the future, been on the python visualizer. Thanks for all the explanations :)

Comment: Do *not* paste a screen capture: cut & paste the message.  We may want to do something with the text when we reply.  This is one of the many details in the introductory tour -- which I hope you review Real Soon Now.  :-)

Comment: Please remember to accept your favourite answer, so Stack Overflow can properly retire the question.  Up-vote whatever you found useful (I already did).

Comment: @AlanWakke Please accept an answer as per http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are after:

```
def count_greater(xs,v):
    count = 0
    for i in xs:
        if i >= v:
            count += 1
    return count
count_greater([12,0,20,34,0,20],3)
```

It returns the number of times that a value in the list is equal to or greater than the second argument (3 in the example). The value returned in this case is 4.

Comment: Any reason not to use `if i >= 3:` instead of 2 `if` conditions

Comment: What would I do if its an unknown list? Would I replace the 3 with 'i'?

Comment: @AlanWakke You mean if the list `xs` was empty? In that case `0` would be returned

Comment: Why did you accept the **v** parameter, but then ignore it?
Hard-coding the target value defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

v is not a list, but a single number, so you do not need to iterate over it.

So this would be sufficient:

```
for i in (xs):
    if i > v:
        count_list += 1
```

There are alternative approaches you could take. For instance, use filter(function, list), like so:

```
list_greater = filter(lambda d: d < v, xs)
count_greater = len(list_greater)
```

This approach has the advantage that you can *work* with the filtered numbers, too, not just count them.

Comment: It needs to be `>=` as per the OP: `greater than v as well as the duplicates`

Comment: Also doesn't work in python3 (need `list(filter(...))`)

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop is syntactically incorrect. You need to iterate over the just `xs`list and check with the value of `v`. For example *to get number greater than and equal to `v` in your `xs`*:

```
def count_get_greater_item(xs,v):
    greater_than_v = []
    for item in xs:
        if item >= v:
            greater_than_v.append(item)
    return greater_than_v 

count_above([22,0,30,44,0,30],5)
```

However, for finding the duplicates (*my understanding is the number occurring in the list more than once*), you may use `collections.Counter()` as:

```
import collections
duplicate_list = []
for item, count in collections.Counter(x).items():
    if count > v:
         duplicate_list.append(item)
```

OR, in one line via *list comprehension* as:

```
duplicate_list = [item for item, count in collections.Counter(xs).items() if count > v]
```

where `xs` and `v` are holding the same value as is mentioned in question

Comment: It needs to be `>=` as per the OP: `greater than v as well as the duplicates`

Comment: I believed by duplicates OP meant he want to get duplicate entries in the list. But you may be also correct because in the sample code, there is nothing related to duplicacy. Updated answer based on your feedback

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in capabilities of the language:

```
def count_greater(xs,v):
    return sum([item >= v for item in xs])

print (count_greater([12,0,20,34,0,20],3))
```

Output is **4**, as expected.

---

In your code, note that `count += 0` does absolutely nothing; remove that and the **else**.  As you suggested, just use **v**; there's no need to iterate **j** over a construct that you know is exactly one item long.

Comment: Just use a generator expression vs. list comprehension - use the built-in capabilities of the language :)

Comment: I didn't want to push OP too far ... taking a guess for current technology level.

Comment: `print()` is not required

Comment: **print** is required to display the value in some execution engines.

Comment: Personally, if you are going to introduce list comprehensions you may as well introduce generator expressions - they are largely the same. Start out using the right tool for the job. If you are going to construct a list then `len([x for x in xs if x >= v])` would do the job.

Comment: Personal experience -- I don't touch generators until my students have mastered loops and functions.  However, your point is well taken: the basic, in-line generator is not harder to comprehend than a comprehension.  :-)  Since **dave** did the generator and **RecencyEffect** got the filter, I think I'll let my example stand, just for variety.

Answer (score 0):

as I understand the working code is it count the values in the list more than v

```
def count_above(xs,v):
    count_list = 0
    for i in xs: # for each i in the list which is xs
        if i > v:
            count_list += 1 
        else: # take care of else space should be under if dircitly
            count_list += 0
    return count_list 

count_above([22,0,30,44,0,30],5)
```

you should take care of your spaces and you loop on a list for each i n the list as i mention in code above

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension to get conditional occurrence counts and sets to identify the (total) number of duplicates:

```
vals = [22,0,30,44,0,30]
ceil = 5

over_ceil_count = len([v for v in vals if v > ceil])

dup_count = len(vals) - len(set(vals))
```

The set automatically removes duplicates, so the difference between the length of the set and the length of the original list tells you how many duplicate values you started with.

Comment: De-dup-ing seems to be counter to the OP's given purpose.